# Can I stop Hibernate from generating union queries when querying fields with inheritance?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, database-performance

I have a JPA hierarchy where one object contains a Set of an abstract type, implemented by a varying number of sub-classes. The problem is that when Hibernate tries to load these classes it generates a query that gets the main object normally, but (lazily) loads these additional objects using a union (in a subselect). Something along the lines of:

```
select ...
from (
    select ...
    from subtable1
    union
    select ...
    from subtable2
)
where parent.id = ?
```

This is an **extremely** inefficient query (with 10k rows in the parent table and 1 of each sub-class for all rows getting the whole hierarchy for 100 or so records in the parent class take several minutes, an eager query takes up to 50 minutes).

What I don't understand is why they're not just left joins from the parent table (`select ... from parent p left join subtable1 ... left join subtable2 ...`) as that would bring all the required data in a fraction of a second. Is there any way I can avoid this silly union query?

So far the only viable solution I've seen is to change inheritance type from TABLE_PER_CLASS to SINGLE_TABLE, but the trade-offs for this are less than ideal (including not being able to use "not null" on columns, maintenance issues since the extended classes will belong to different teams that may even be working with different versions of the software, etc.).

Just in case it helps anyone, I'll paste a real query as generated by Hibernate with this relationship (the JPQL is as a comment at the start), this particular query took 34 seconds to execute on its own (0.6 seconds when rewritten as left joins):

```
/* select distinct p
   from PersonJpa p left join fetch p.addressOfRecords a
   left join fetch a.extensions e left join fetch a.commsType c
   left join fetch p.credentials cr left join fetch cr.type t
   left join fetch p.serviceProfiles s left join fetch s.extensions ex
   where p.id in (?1) */
SELECT DISTINCT personjpa0_.person_id AS person1_902_0_,
                addressofr1_.aor_id AS aor1_899_1_,
                extensions2_.id AS id903_2_,
                commstypej3_.comms_type AS comms1_908_3_,
                credential4_.credentials_id AS credenti1_905_4_,
                credential5_.credentials_type AS credenti1_904_5_,
                servicepro6_.service_profile_id AS service1_901_6_,
                extensions7_.id AS id907_7_,
                personjpa0_.display_name AS display2_902_0_,
                personjpa0_.first_name AS first3_902_0_,
                personjpa0_.initials AS initials902_0_,
                personjpa0_.last_name AS last5_902_0_,
                personjpa0_.title AS title902_0_,
                personjpa0_.user_name AS user7_902_0_,
                addressofr1_.comms_type AS comms9_899_1_,
                addressofr1_.display_form AS display2_899_1_,
                addressofr1_.domain AS domain899_1_,
                addressofr1_.label AS label899_1_,
                addressofr1_.parameters AS parameters899_1_,
                addressofr1_.person_id AS person10_899_1_,
                addressofr1_.preference AS preference899_1_,
                addressofr1_.send_html AS send7_899_1_,
                addressofr1_.service_profile_id AS service11_899_1_,
                addressofr1_.user_part AS user8_899_1_,
                addressofr1_.person_id AS person10_0__,
                addressofr1_.aor_id AS aor1_0__,
                extensions2_.aor_id AS aor2_903_2_,
                extensions2_.resolution_status AS resolution1_910_2_,
                extensions2_.certificate_serial_number AS certific1_914_2_,
                extensions2_.device_type_name AS device2_914_2_,
                extensions2_.provisioned AS provisio3_914_2_,
                extensions2_.provisioning_token AS provisio4_914_2_,
                extensions2_.provisioning_unique_id AS provisio5_914_2_,
                extensions2_.sip_password AS sip6_914_2_,
                extensions2_.username AS username914_2_,
                extensions2_.voicemail_long_timeout AS voicemail8_914_2_,
                extensions2_.voicemail_short_timeout AS voicemail9_914_2_,
                extensions2_.clazz_ AS clazz_2_,
                extensions2_.aor_id AS aor2_1__,
                extensions2_.id AS id1__,
                credential4_.algorithm_name AS algorithm3_905_4_,
                credential4_.password AS password905_4_,
                credential4_.person_id AS person4_905_4_,
                credential4_.realm_id AS realm5_905_4_,
                credential4_.credentials_type AS credenti6_905_4_,
                credential4_.person_id AS person4_2__,
                credential4_.credentials_id AS credenti1_2__,
                servicepro6_.name AS name901_6_,
                servicepro6_.person_id AS person3_901_6_,
                servicepro6_.person_id AS person3_3__,
                servicepro6_.service_profile_id AS service1_3__,
                extensions7_.service_profile_id AS service2_907_7_,
                extensions7_.seqprofile_id AS seqprofile1_911_7_,
                extensions7_.certificate_port AS certific1_915_7_,
                extensions7_.email_aor_id AS email23_915_7_,
                extensions7_.emergency_numbers AS emergency2_915_7_,
                extensions7_.from_domain AS from3_915_7_,
                extensions7_.outbound_domain AS outbound4_915_7_,
                extensions7_.pbx_aor_id AS pbx24_915_7_,
                extensions7_.provisioning_delivery AS provisio5_915_7_,
                extensions7_.provisioning_host AS provisio6_915_7_,
                extensions7_.provisioning_port AS provisio7_915_7_,
                extensions7_.server_access_call_control_port AS server8_915_7_,
                extensions7_.server_access_host AS server9_915_7_,
                extensions7_.server_access_number AS server10_915_7_,
                extensions7_.server_access_secure_mode AS server11_915_7_,
                extensions7_.sip_domain AS sip12_915_7_,
                extensions7_.sip_enabled AS sip13_915_7_,
                extensions7_.sip_expires AS sip14_915_7_,
                extensions7_.sip_proxy AS sip15_915_7_,
                extensions7_.sip_realm AS sip16_915_7_,
                extensions7_.sip_transport AS sip17_915_7_,
                extensions7_.voicemail_long_timeout AS voicemail18_915_7_,
                extensions7_.voicemail_message_server AS voicemail19_915_7_,
                extensions7_.voicemail_number AS voicemail20_915_7_,
                extensions7_.voicemail_short_timeout AS voicemail21_915_7_,
                extensions7_.voicemail_userid AS voicemail22_915_7_,
                extensions7_.clazz_ AS clazz_7_,
                extensions7_.service_profile_id AS service2_4__,
                extensions7_.id AS id4__
FROM   cdm.cdm_person AS personjpa0_
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       cdm.cdm_address_of_record AS addressofr1_
       ON personjpa0_.person_id = addressofr1_.person_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (SELECT NULL AS device_type_name,
               id,
               NULL AS provisioning_unique_id,
               aor_id,
               NULL AS voicemail_long_timeout,
               NULL AS username,
               NULL AS certificate_serial_number,
               NULL AS provisioning_token,
               resolution_status,
               NULL AS voicemail_short_timeout,
               NULL AS provisioned,
               NULL AS sip_password,
               1 AS clazz_
        FROM   cdm.sb_aor_details
        UNION
        SELECT device_type_name,
               id,
               provisioning_unique_id,
               aor_id,
               voicemail_long_timeout,
               username,
               certificate_serial_number,
               provisioning_token,
               NULL AS resolution_status,
               voicemail_short_timeout,
               provisioned,
               sip_password,
               2 AS clazz_
        FROM   cdm.fmc_remote_number_address_of_record_extension) AS extensions2_
       ON addressofr1_.aor_id = extensions2_.aor_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       cdm.cdm_comms_type AS commstypej3_
       ON addressofr1_.comms_type = commstypej3_.comms_type
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       cdm.cdm_credentials AS credential4_
       ON personjpa0_.person_id = credential4_.person_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       cdm.cdm_credentials_type AS credential5_
       ON credential4_.credentials_type = credential5_.credentials_type
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       cdm.cdm_service_profile AS servicepro6_
       ON personjpa0_.person_id = servicepro6_.person_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (SELECT NULL AS server_access_host,
               NULL AS sip_domain,
               NULL AS voicemail_message_server,
               NULL AS outbound_domain,
               NULL AS emergency_numbers,
               NULL AS provisioning_delivery,
               id,
               NULL AS sip_expires,
               NULL AS pbx_aor_id,
               NULL AS server_access_call_control_port,
               NULL AS provisioning_port,
               NULL AS email_aor_id,
               NULL AS voicemail_number,
               NULL AS voicemail_long_timeout,
               NULL AS certificate_port,
               NULL AS sip_enabled,
               NULL AS sip_transport,
               NULL AS server_access_number,
               service_profile_id,
               NULL AS server_access_secure_mode,
               NULL AS voicemail_userid,
               seqprofile_id,
               NULL AS sip_realm,
               NULL AS voicemail_short_timeout,
               NULL AS provisioning_host,
               NULL AS from_domain,
               NULL AS sip_proxy,
               1 AS clazz_
        FROM   cdm.sb_service_profile_details
        UNION
        SELECT server_access_host,
               sip_domain,
               voicemail_message_server,
               outbound_domain,
               emergency_numbers,
               provisioning_delivery,
               id,
               sip_expires,
               pbx_aor_id,
               server_access_call_control_port,
               provisioning_port,
               email_aor_id,
               voicemail_number,
               voicemail_long_timeout,
               certificate_port,
               sip_enabled,
               sip_transport,
               server_access_number,
               service_profile_id,
               server_access_secure_mode,
               voicemail_userid,
               NULL AS seqprofile_id,
               sip_realm,
               voicemail_short_timeout,
               provisioning_host,
               from_domain,
               sip_proxy,
               2 AS clazz_
        FROM   cdm.fmc_service_profile_extension) AS extensions7_
       ON servicepro6_.service_profile_id = extensions7_.service_profile_id
WHERE  personjpa0_.person_id IN (1, 2, [continuous ids], 199, 200);
```

Comment: Can you use Join Inheritance Strategy? If so, use it with a discriminator on Base table; Hibernate supports this feature using .hbm.xml configuration (it didn't work on previous versions of configuring with annotations, I'm not sure about recent releases).

Comment: I'll give it a go. I'm using Hibernate 3.3.1 and annotations, can I mix annotations and xml configuration without problems?

Comment: I know you can mix them, but you must have mapped your base case class using .hbm.xml, so you could user Join strategy with discriminator column. (Just refer to Hibernate documentations).

Comment: None of my classes are mapped with .hbm.xml, they're all mapped at runtime (many of them aren't known at compile time). I've tried it though and it seems to work with annotations (haven't finished all my tests yet, but it's looking good). It's an additional table, but that's a small price to pay for such a huge performance increase. Thanks a lot.